# Close an sqlite3 database on exit, no matter what

Tags: python, error-handling, sqlite, resource-cleanup

I'm currently writing a script that uses sqlite3. I recently ran into a problem with the database being in use by another program due to my code exiting early with an error.

With similar problems, one usually uses:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(...)
try:
    #Do stuff
finally:
    conn.close()
```

But this won't work in my case. In a nutshell, this is my code:

import sqlite3

```
class Thingamadoodle:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(...)
        ...

    #Methods and stuff

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

poop = Thingamadoodle(...)
poop.do_stuff(...)
poop.throw_irritating_exception_that_you_cant_track_down(irritatingness=11)
```

After the program exits without closing the connection, I get errors when I try to modify the database.

Is there a way to safely close the connection, even on an unclean exit?

Comment: [Using the connection as a context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager)

Comment: @hus787 Thanks, I'll use that, but I still don't think it fixes my problem. It guards against corruption but won't _close_ the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, i don't understand the question much, but why not just wrap the `poop.do_stuff()` in a `try/except` block?

```
try:
    poop.do_stuff()
except:
    poop.__del__()
finally:
    poop.__del__()
```

Or to be a bit cleaner, use a context manager:

```
class Thingamadoodle:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    #Methods and stuff
    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(...)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, errorType, errorValue, errorTrace):
        self.conn.close()
```

And just execute it as:

```
with Thingmadoodle(args) as poop:
    #do things
```

After all the code is done, or after an exception happened in the statement, `__exit__` will be executed, and you can safely close it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess I could, but I don't really want to clutter up my code with those.

Comment: Thanks! This a lot cleaner, and as far as I know, I can also pass `poop` to functions without it going out of the context manager. Right?

Comment: Yep, as long it's in the `with` block.